# Adding a Revolution Slider to Kentico 7

Tags: jquery, slider, kentico

I am trying to put a custom banner slider using the JavaScript jquery.themepunch.revolution and jquery.themepunch.plugins.min into my site using Kentico 7. How would I go about that process to have this on my home page?

Answer (score 2):

Your first step would be to decide what information you wanted to show. Typically, this will be a collection documents (images) in your content tree. Once you have your collection, you will use a transformation to decide the layout for each item you want to display.

http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/7_0/controls/cmsrepeater_overview.htm

For you JS, you will need to include the appropriate libraries on the page. You can do this in the Master Page (if you want it on all pages), using the JS web part (which is good for a single page that needs it), or even on a Page Template level (if you had many pages that need the functionality and all use the same template).

Once you have the JS in place, you will need update your transformation to have the proper layout to match the JS library. Typically with sliders, each "image" will need a specific tag or attribute. You can easily add this to the transformation you use to display the content.

While Version 7 is pretty old (3+ years), you can still find a lot of documentation and info in the Developer's Guide here:

http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/7_0/devguide/index.html

Comment: Thank you, I am working on this now and will update you with the results. Thank you

Comment: I fixed the issue in Kentico 7, now that we upgraded to Kentico 8 the slider is broken. Would the JS have anything to do with this error?

Comment: It's possible that there is a conflict in JS scripts being included. With V8, there was big overhaul to the admin UI and a lot more use of jQuery and other libraries. I suspect that might be factoring in.

You may be able to find some more answers here: http://devnet.kentico.com/articles/using-a-custom-jquery-when-developing-pages-in-kentico

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple banners with a background image, text content, and link, you might want to consider using a custom document type. That would make it easier to manage the content. Then as Bryan suggested, you would create the transformations and display the data using a repeater.

Kentico Documentation: [Creating custom document types](https://devnet.kentico.com/docs/7_0/devguide/index.html?defining_a_new_document_type.htm)

Blog: [Working with javascript carousel sliders in Kentico](http://www.imediainc.com/blog/july-2015/working-javascript-carousel-sliders-in-kentico)